# Issue when try to invoke Javascript Library in Blazor that produce visible user interface elements

Tags: javascript, .net, asp.net-core, blazor

I am trying to invoke Tyro's online payment javascript to create the payment form for my project. But it doesn't work as my expected. (Refer to https://docs.connect.tyro.com/app/apis/pay/accept-an-online-payment/)

HTML:

```
 <form id="pay-form">
     <div id="tyro-pay-form">
     <!--Tyro.js injects the Pay Input Fields -->
     </div>
     <button id="pay-form-submit" hidde=@tyroPayForm_hide>Pay</button>
 </form>
```

.razor:

```
 TyroPayResponse res = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<TyroPayResponse>(result);
                            string paySecret = res.paySecret;
 IJSObjectReference tyro;

 tyro = await JsRuntime.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("import","https://pay.connect.tyro.com/v1/tyro.js");                         
 await tyro.InvokeVoidAsync("init", paySecret);

 var payForm = await tyro.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("createPayForm");
 await payForm.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("inject", "#tyro-pay-form");
```

When I get the response and use the paySecret to invoke this external javascript, it doesn't show the payform that should be injected into the html.

I searched Microsoft official document, and I belive it has relevants with this part (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/call-javascript-from-dotnet?view=aspnetcore-6.0#javascript-libraries-that-render-ui)

So I introduce the ElementReference, while I create a new element in html

```
<div @ref="tyropayform"></div>
```

and use it by

```
private ElementReference tyropayform;

...

var payForm = await tyro.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("createPayForm");
await payForm.InvokeAsync<IJSObjectReference>("inject", tyropayform);
```

It doen't work, but I am not suprised. The javascript funtion payForm.inject(selector) may not support with the element args.

As a learner of Blazor, I am not sure is there something I made a mistake or it is just because the external javascript function is not supported by Blazor when it try to render the UI. Can Someone give me any suggetions?

Comment: I got an error of 
Could not find 'init' ('init' was undefined).
Error: Could not find 'init' ('init' was undefined).
Does it means I use an incorrect invoke to this javascript? (Which cause it can't find the function that should be there)

Comment: Have you followed this to reference external js https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/javascript-interoperability/?view=aspnetcore-8.0#javascript-location

Comment: Yes. I have include this external js reference in the <head> part in index.html, it doesn't work.